# Rails: Make a new User record, analyze the data, then create a new Hipster only if the data returns true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to take in some User data via a form, then analyze some of that data with my User.rb methods. If the data returns true, I want to create a new Hipster record.

I *only* want to save Hipster records, not User records. Generic User records are useless to me.

The easiest way would be to have a single Hipster model and just create a bunch of custom validations before saving. Here is my current code:

Hipster.rb

```
validate :hipster_status, :on => :create

def hipster_status
  has_a_bike?
  has_a_moustache?
  has_skinny_jeans?

  unless hipster?
    self.errors.add("aint a hipster")
  end

end

def has_a_bike?
 # run some code to see if User has a bike
end

def has_a_moustache?
 # run some code to see if User has a moustache
end

def has_skinny_jeans?
 # run some code to see if User has skinny jeans
end

def hipster?
 has_a_bike? && has_a_moustache? && has_skinny_jeans?
end
```

But it feels wrong to have these methods in the Hipster model. It feels weird to be calling `hipster.hipster?` I feel like I should be creating a temporary User, then calling `user.hipster?` if it returns true, then create a Hipster (never even saving the User).

But I'm having a hard time visualizing the new architecture. When a user visits the User#new page, they post a form to User#create ? But I don't want to create a User. Is it okay to post to User#create with no intention of creating a record?

Or am I just overthinking it and should stick to the first version?

Comment: A hipster is a user with certain attributes so I'm not really convinced you need the Hipster class at all. I don't know what's the use case for your models but one option is to create an `Accessory` model to store the different user accessories in a has_many association. Things like bike, moustache, skinny_jeans can all be stored as accessories and new ones can be added at any time so it scales pretty well. You can create a user and add/check on those accessories to determine whether a `user.is_hipster?` or `user.is_geek?` or `user.is_android_fanboy?` etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rog's comment. If you're going to have users with lots of Accessories or other extra attributes, make an associated model.

If a bike, mustache, and skinny jeans are the only things you're interested in, and you're using a database that supports array serialization like Postgres, your could do something a little simpler like like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # add a text column to the users table named accessories
  serialize :accessories, Array

  def has_accessory(accessory_name)
    accessories.include? accessory_name
  end

  def is_hipster?
    has_accessory('bike') && has_accessory('mustache') && has_accessory('skinny jeans')
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess it just feels redundant because I won't have any users who aren't hipsters in the database. All of my saved Users will be hipsters